# C# Array.IndexOf is static function, why?

Tags: c#, oop, static, abstract-class, object-oriented-analysis

I journey my mock interview practice. In Nov. 2017, I came cross the issue to write C# `Array.IndexOf`, I was confused and did not know that I should write `IndexOf` as a static function of abstract class Array. I try to learn object-oriented design through C# Array class. Please give me some reasons why C# Array `IndexOf` is designed to be static but `SetValue` is public but not static. I read C# Array class source code, I could not figure out why. If the analysis can be based on C# Array class source code, that will be nice.

I learn C# using C# 2000 things starting from Sept. 20, 2017. Here is my post: https://datastructurealgorithmmockinterviewfactsandtips.quora.com/Understanding-C-Array-class

Please advice. I like to learn by myself object-oriented design by asking questions on existing C# Array abstract class.

Comment: This was a design decision made by Microsoft when they created the .Net-Framework.

Comment: Why does Array.SetValue not set as static?